# Width on table cell that have fixed table layout don't work

Tags: css, html-table

I have code like this:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>J</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

why cells don't have width of 120px? I want the width of the table to be bigger then the width of the div so I can scroll the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div {
  overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>J</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you only need to set width of the table to any value (smaller then the result width) in pixels?

Comment: If you want a table to be scrollable inside the div then the width of the table should be greater.

Comment: Setting the table width to 600 and the div to 300 sounds more logical and works also.